# What exactly do the rails g ember:install command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I almost done configuring a Rails project to make use of the EmberJS framework. I'm using the two recommended gems for this

```ruby
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source'
```

I already complete the

```
rails g ember:bootstrap
```

command but when i use

```
rails g ember:install
```

i get the following error:

```
create  vendor/assets/ember/development/ember.js
downloading:  http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js -> vendor/assets/ember/development/ember.js
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

So yes, this is a connection related issue since i work mainly in an **offline** environment.

That said here is my specific question.

What exactly do the previous command to do it manually by myself ?? The answer is pretty straightforward for anyone that do this before.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/ember/install_generator.rb) it looks like it fetches the specified version of Ember and places it in the `vendor/assets/ember` directory.

Comment: Well it works, simply download the mentioned files in the script, put it in the specific folders and that's it. Work's like charm.